# How to write in kernel mode to some process's virtual memory

Tags: module, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, context-switch

I want to use my Unix module in order to write to another process memory (I would like to do it in kernel mode and avoid the pthread interface).
I have to use function (like do_mmap(..), do_unmmap(..), sys_mprotect(..), etc.) which affect the current process memory instead of the process I'd like to it to affect.

So I figured, I need find a way to do a context switch to the process I want in order to make the process I want the current. I tried to copy the implementation of the schedule() with a minor change:
I replaced the line:

next = pick_next_task(rq);

with:

next = myNext;

My problem is that schedule requires so much structs and functions which I can't include, so I have to re-implement them. it seems pretty bad to do such a thing. Do you have any suggestions?

I want to avoid to modify the existing kernel, so I won't have to force the users to restart and modify their operating system in order to use my program (which is why I use modules).

By the way, I use the "2.6.38-11-generic" version of Linux.

Comment: Does your code run in process context or in BH/interrupt context?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [get_user_pages()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/mm/memory.c#L1876) function to get the pages of the target process (more precisely, its mm_struct)
2. Map the page(s) that you need via `kmap()` or `kmap_atomic()` (depending on the context)
3. Write/read at the address returned by the mapping (withing a page size).
4. Destroy the mapping via `kunmap()` or `kunmap_atomic()`

Comment: `put_page` is also needed, to be used after `kunmap`. Also, `set_page_dirty` should be called if the page has been written to.